# Android : Sliding Left and Right functionality for playing previous and next songs

Tags: java, android, animation

I have to implement slide left and right now playing bar in order to play previous and next song.I have to make whole now playing bar movable after left and right slide.

I have tried implementing `ViewPager` but due to that I lost Sliding UP functionality of that Playing bar.I have huge code with me.So by making minimum changes in the layouts how can I implement swipe left and right functionality.

Comment: -1 Just not information for us to help you - what specific things have you tried, what exact functionality do you want?

Comment: I have to implement same as google music player.When I add 2 or more songs in play queue,after left and right swipe,I can go to the prev or next song.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked google music it is doing exactly the same what you are asking for with drawer enabled and viewpager need to used in this case.

Swapping will only do the swapping of the fragment not the whole page..

May it helps you :)

Comment: Yes I have checked google music player.I am having the same idea but I cannot integrate it in my code.

Comment: I have ViewPager and in that ViewPager adapter I am opening the NowPlayingFragment having all current playing information.But when I am adding new songs to playqueue,it is not reflecting in the ViewPager adapter and I cannot fetch the details.

Comment: ashish.pathak24@gmail.com